# displaying error messages with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Here is my form:

```
= form_for @talent do |f|

  - if @talent.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= pluralize(@talent.errors.count, "error")
      "prohibited this user from being saved:"
         %ul - @talent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
           %li= msg

  = f.label :First_Name
  = f.text_field :first_name
  = f.label :Last_Name
  = f.text_field :last_name
  = f.label :City
  = f.text_field :city
  = f.label :State
  = f.text_field :state
  = f.label :Zip_code
  = f.text_field :zip_code
  = f.label :Email
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.submit "Create"
```

Here is my error message:

```
Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.

Extracted source (around line #7):

4:     #error_explanation
5:       %h2= pluralize(@talent.errors.count, "error")
6:       "prohibited this user from being saved:"
7:         %ul - @talent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
8:           %li= msg
9: 
10:   = f.label :First_Name
```

i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your `%ul` line should be by itself, with the loop under it. Also, your `%ul` line shouldn't be indented under the string above:

```
- if @talent.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    %h2= pluralize(@talent.errors.count, "error")
    "prohibited this user from being saved:"
    %ul
      - @talent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

But what you probably want is for the "prohibited..." part to be part of your `h2`? If so:

```
- if @talent.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    %h2
      = pluralize(@talent.errors.count, "error")
      "prohibited this user from being saved:"
    %ul 
      - @talent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are putting multiple things inside a tag, as you are for your `h2`, you need to indent them all rather than inlining one and adding a second. Haml thinks you are trying to nest your `ul` inside the text above it.

```
= form_for @talent do |f|

  - if @talent.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@talent.errors.count, "error")
        "prohibited this user from being saved:"
      %ul - @talent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

Or if you didn't want the text inside the `h2` you've just got the indentation for your `ul` wrong. Bring it back two spaces.

```
#error_explanation
  %h2= pluralize(@talent.errors.count, "error")
  "prohibited this user from being saved:"
  %ul - @talent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    %li= msg
```